# AVAssetExportSession doesn't preserve the original date and time (macOS)

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avasset, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to transcode an H.264 to HEVC file in m4v format, and I'm having problems getting AVAssetExportSession to preserve the CreateDate of the original file. I have tried forcing the value by applying the original date using metadata values, but this only results in a new QuickTime tag, DateTimeOriginal being created. The CreateDate, TrackCreateDate, and MediaCreateDate, all take the current date and time.

This is the code I'm using (in a macOS playground).

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "input.mp4"))

AVAssetExportSession.determineCompatibility(ofExportPreset: AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality, with: videoAsset, outputFileType: AVFileType.m4v, completionHandler: { (isCompatible) in
    if !isCompatible {
        print("Format not compatible.")
        return
    }})

if (AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: videoAsset).contains(AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality)) {
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality)

    exporter?.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "output.mp4")
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4v
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter?.canPerformMultiplePassesOverSourceMediaData = true

    let creationDate = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    creationDate.keySpace = videoAsset.creationDate?.keySpace
    creationDate.key = videoAsset.creationDate?.key
    creationDate.value = videoAsset.creationDate?.value
    print(creationDate)

    var newMetaData = videoAsset.metadata
    newMetaData.append(creationDate)
    print(newMetaData)

    exporter?.metadata = newMetaData

    exporter?.exportAsynchronously{() -> Void in
        switch exporter!.status {
        case .failed:
            print("Export failed: \(String(describing: exporter?.error?.localizedDescription))")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Export canceled.")
        case .completed:
            print("Successful!")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
else {
    print("Preset not compatible.")
}
```

The times generally look like this (where the July date is original, and the September date is current):

```
---- File ----
FileModifyDate: 2018:09:24 23:51:12+08:00
FileAccessDate: 2018:09:24 23:53:22+08:00
FileInodeChangeDate: 2018:09:24 23:51:12+08:00
---- QuickTime ----
CreateDate: 2018:09:24 15:49:50
ModifyDate: 2018:09:24 15:51:12
TrackCreateDate: 2018:09:24 15:49:50
TrackModifyDate: 2018:09:24 15:51:12
MediaCreateDate: 2018:09:24 15:49:50
MediaModifyDate: 2018:09:24 15:51:12
DateTimeOriginal: 2018:07:16 19:59:03Z
```